# Criar laço FOR em classe PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, for, herança

A fim de Estudos estou tentando criar um laço for no método construct, mas esta dando erro e não estou conseguindo achar meu erro.
esse o erro que aparece:

> Notice: Undefined variable: funcionario in C:\laragon\www\Funcionario.php on line 4

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in
> C:\laragon\www\Funcionario.php on line 4

Meu código:

```
    declare(strict_types = 1);

    include_once 'Colaborador.php';
    include_once 'Funcionario.php';

    $funcionario = new Funcionario("João da Silva\n", "1986-03-10\n", 2250.00);
    $funcionario->nome = "João da Silva \n";
    $funcionario->data = "1986-03-10\n";
    $funcionario->salario = 2250.00;
    
    echo $funcionario->exibir();
```

Class Pai:

```
 class Colaborador{
        var $nome;
        var $data;
        var $salario;

       public function __construct($nome, $data, $salario){
            $this->nome = $nome; 
            $this->data = $data;
            $this->salario = $salario;
        }

        public function getNome():string{
            return $this->nome;
        }
        public function getData_nascimento():string{
            return $this->data;
        }
        public function getSalario():float{
            return $this->salario;
        }
    }
```

Código da class filho:

```
 class Funcionario extends Colaborador {
        function exibir(){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($funcionario); $i++){

        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: $funcionario deveria ser um array (uma lista). Para descobrir o que ele é você pode usar o var_dump($funcionario).

Comment: Onde está o construtor da classe? E parece que faltou declarar outros membros da classe, as propriedades a serem preenchidas pelo construtor...

Comment: E que no exercício pede assim.

Comment: Ele me da oq deve ter e eu que me vire para fazer.

Comment: @GabrielFelipe no seu método exibir, count($funcionario), $funcionário não foi nem definido. Você quer exibir exatamente o quê? Nome, data e salário?

Comment: os trés  eu tinha declarado antes mas estava dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Acho melhor postar o que te pediram no exercício, sem saber o que é exatamente, fica complicado. Posso dizer que você pode/deve remover o for e usar echo $this->getNome(); echo $this->getData_nascimento(); $this->getSalario(); mas talvez o for faça parte do exercício e aí teria que entender melhor o que se pede. Uma leitura [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy) talvez ajude.

Comment: Pseh, isso que e o complicado

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma outra forma de solucionar meu problema, vi que não teria como usar o laço for em uma class filho, ent coloquei foreach na principal, e criei um array com os objetos.

```
declare(strict_types = 1);

   include_once 'Colaborador.php';
   include_once 'Funcionario.php';
   require_once 'Estagiario.php';

  echo "\n Funcionarios \n";
   $funcionarios = [];
  
   $f1 = new Funcionario("João da Silva", "1986-03-10", 2250.00);
   $f2 = new Funcionario("Roberto Felipe", "1999-04-16", 2000.00);
   $f3 = new Funcionario("Leonardo Lima", "2001-08-25", 2100.00);
   $f4 = new Funcionario("Renato Augusto", "1979-04-01", 2000.00);

   array_push($funcionarios, $f1);
   array_push($funcionarios, $f2);
   array_push($funcionarios, $f3);
   array_push($funcionarios, $f4);

   foreach($funcionarios as $modelos => $caracteristica){
     echo "$modelos\n";
     foreach($caracteristica as $caracteristicas=>$valor){
         echo "$caracteristicas=>$valor\n";
     }
 }
  echo "\n Estagiarios \n";

  $estagiarios = [];

   $es1 = new Estagiario('José de Souza' , '2004-10-01', 1212.00);
   $es2 = new Estagiario('Diego Costa' , '2002-07-07', 1000.00);
   $es3 = new Estagiario('Douglas Silva' , '2000-02-29', 960.00);

   array_push($estagiarios, $es1);
   array_push($estagiarios, $es2);
   array_push($estagiarios, $es3);

   foreach($estagiarios as $modelos => $caracteristica){
     echo "$modelos\n";
     foreach($caracteristica as $caracteristicas=>$valor){
         echo "$caracteristicas=>$valor\n";
     }
 }
```